# Get selected Datagrid cell value by double click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to know, if it is possible to get selected DataGrid value by double clicking on the desired cell.

I have used this method, so the user can select the desired cell and press CTRL + C to get it into the clipboard, but it is possible to double click on the selected cell and then have it in clipboard in some way?

```
private void OrdersGrid_OnCopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
   var currentCell = e.ClipboardRowContent[OrdersGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex];
   e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
   e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(currentCell);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by myself.

The solution to get the selected value on cell by double clicking.

```
private void OrdersGrid_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{           
     var cellInfo = OrdersGrid.CurrentCell;
     {
         var column = cellInfo.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
         if (column != null)
         {
              var element = new FrameworkElement() { DataContext = cellInfo.Item };
              BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, TagProperty, column.Binding);
              var cellValue = element.Tag;
              Clipboard.SetText(cellValue.ToString());
         }
     }                   
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you are using WPF, you better familiarize yourself with [WPF Commands](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/).